# The name 'Model' does not exist - after git pull

Tags: git, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I have problem with intellisense in Visual Studio 2013 with MVC 5 app. We are small team and after pull GIT repo(sync in VS) intellisense lost `@model` or for example `@Html.LabelFor`.

I tried a lot of configurations of web.configs. After some time it works but unfortunately I could not find out why. And after next sycs problem again. On the repo there aren't any changes of project/configuration files (`web.configs`, `.csproj`, `atp`) visible.

Thanks for any help or tips.

EDIT:

Its interesting that intellisense know `@Html.Label` but not `@Html.LabelFor` even if both helpers are from one `System.Web.Mvc.dll`. Isnt it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It resolves upgrade VS to 2013 update 2.